# Alacritty throws "E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo" when running "htop" and "Error opening terminal: alacritty." when opening files with vim

Tags: terminal

The errors

> Terminal entry not found in terminfo

and

> Error opening terminal: alacritty

happen to me on a legacy server when I `ssh`'ed to it like:

```sh
ssh MY_USER@MY_SERVER
```

and use Alacritty to open text files with `vi MY_TEXT_FILE`.

The following is just a warning that does not keep me from working with the file in vim, but starts with these lines whenever I look up a vim file:

```sh
E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo
'alacritty' not known. Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_amiga
    builtin_beos-ansi
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_pcansi
    builtin_win32
    builtin_vt320
    builtin_vt52
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_debug
    builtin_dumb
defaulting to 'ansi'
```

The other error `Error opening terminal: alacritty.` is worse since you cannot run some commands then, happens to me with `htop` to see all of the pids.

The two errors come up likely for the same thing. How to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is taken from [Nano/vim in SSH session respond with "Error opening terminal: alacritty." and other weird things. #3360](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/3360) which then turned out to avoid the other `E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo` as well.

Run:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

if you are already on the server.

Run:

```
TERM=xterm-256color ssh
```

if you want to make an environment variable already on your local machine that you want to pass to any `ssh` command.

Mind that you will use the terminal "xterm" then, which has less features than Alacritty. I use the xterm only for `htop` and `top` commands and other commands that do not accept Alacritty and throw `'alacritty': unknown terminal type.`
If you want to use Alacritty afterwards again, for example for the nice mouse-based copy feature so that you can copy more text than just what can be seen in the terminal page, see [How to copy a large terminal history from Alacritty to the system so that I can search and document - the clipboard seems to get cut](https://superuser.com/questions/1715853/how-to-copy-a-large-terminal-history-from-alacritty-to-the-system-so-that-i-can/1715855#1715855), change back to:

```
TERM=alacritty
```

I also get other terminals listed when I open a file in vim, mind that this is a legacy server.

```sh
Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_amiga
    builtin_beos-ansi
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_pcansi
    builtin_win32
    builtin_vt320
    builtin_vt52
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_debug
    builtin_dumb
defaulting to 'ansi'
```

Thus, you might try those on your server, for example with the one to which it should default anyway:

```
TERM=ansi
```

Not all of the terminal names of the list work directly, for example, `TERM=amiga` does not work for me although it is built-in.